# Julia 1.0 Pkg.add() not working as expected

Tags: julia

I am having trouble adding some packages in Julia

This is one example, although I am finding many others:

```
julia> Pkg.add("QuartzImageIO.jl")
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
* QuartzImageIO.jl (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
```

I believe this should work according to the docs

https://github.com/JuliaIO/QuartzImageIO.jl

and Plotly that required it

```
LoadError: ArgumentError: Package QuartzImageIO not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("QuartzImageIO")` to install the 
QuartzImageIO package.
```

I am new to Julia, am I doing something wrong?
Thanks
Peter

Comment: Got a little closer:  

(JuliaPro_v1.0.1.1) pkg> add https://github.com/JuliaIO/QuartzImageIO.jl.git
   Cloning git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaIO/QuartzImageIO.jl.git`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaIO/QuartzImageIO.jl.git`
[ Info: Assigning UUID 78765569-32a5-5bbe-9417-94cfcda915dd to QuartzImageIO
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * julia (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.

And in QuartzImageIO::REQUIRE I found julia 0.7

Comment: So maybe Julia 1.0 breaks lots of packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install JuliaPro then the packages that you can install are limited by what's been curated for JuliaPro. Installed the non-pro vanilla version and try again.

Comment: Thanks.  Message from N00B to JuliaPro developers: you need your own set of JuliaPro examples because the standard plotting tutorials don't work

Answer (score 2):

The `.jl` suffix is not part of the package name (although packages are often referenced with it included) . Try

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("QuartzImageIO")
```

Comment: Thanks, but no love :-(  julia> Pkg.add("QuartzImageIO")
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * QuartzImageIO (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.

Comment: Works for me. Do you have a corrupted registry? What if you delete `~/.julia/registries` and try again?
Edit: I saw from your comments above that you are using JuliaPro. JuliaPro have their own registry with only a subset of all packages available, see e.g. https://discourse.julialang.org/t/physicalconstants-package-with-julia-1-0-1-1/16189/5

Comment: Yup!  That was it :-D  I got rid of JuliaPro, installed Julia v1.0.1, and now everything is happy.  Guess I'll just stick with the command line REPL

Comment: You can install Juno without using JuliaPro.